# How to show the cursor in tableview cell textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

[image]
I taken textfield and edit button within tableView cell  when i press particular cell button i shown the cursor and button image changed and i called api on this. If i click button again cursor are not showing in textfield.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Assign tag to your edit button in cell for row at IndexPath.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      cell.editButton.tag = indexpath.row;
}
```

get reference to your cell here based on its indexpath. Make its textfield as first Responder.

```
- (IBAction)editButtonClicked:(id)sender{
       UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;  
       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:button.tag inSection:0];
       CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       [cell.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: I taken textfield hard coded in table cell [cell.yourTextField becomeFirstResponder]; this property how to add, i added like this but is not coming exact    UIButton *button1 = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:button1.tag inSection:0];
  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView_EditCategory cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath1];
   
    [cell.contentView addSubview:txtFld_EmailEditCategory];
    [txtFld_EmailEditCategory becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: update code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath in your question

Comment: Hello, particular cell textfield cursor is coming, i want only one button image will be highlighted, here all button image  highlighted, only at a time single button image and cursor will be highlighted.